BPSK modulation with Eb/N0 computation
Good Morning to everyone.
My goal is to create a BPSK modulated signal starting from Eb/N0.
The signal is composed by I-Q components both modulated using BPSK and pulse shaped with squared-root raised cosine filter.
I tried to modulate and demodulate the signal and then to compute Eb/N0 to obtain the starting values but there is somenthing wrong.
I start with Eb/N0 computation to find the Signal Power and the Noise Power. At the end of all computation, I should obtain the same initial values.
BW is my bandwidth while Rb is my bitrate
EbN0 = 4;
CN = EbN0 + pow2db(Rb/BW);               % [dB]
NoiseMu = 0;
NoiseSigma = 20;     
NoiseTemp = (NoiseMu + NoiseSigma .* randn(SamplesNum, 1));
N = pow2db(rms(NoiseTemp)^2) + 3;          % +3dB = Multiply by 2 to have both I and Q components

I think there is a formula to compute sigma starting from Eb/N0 but i cannot find any working formula, so for now I compute the Noise Power N using a fixed sigma
C = CN + N;                                 % [dB]
CN0 = CN + pow2db(BW);                      % [dBHz]
% Carrier Power Share [dB]
CarrierPow_I = pow2db(db2pow(C) * PowShare_I_Perc); % 0.1 power share
CarrierPow_Q = pow2db(db2pow(C) * PowShare_Q_Perc); % 0.9 power share

% Carrier Amplitude [?]
CarrierAmpl_I = 2*sqrt(2*db2pow(CarrierPow_I));
CarrierAmpl_Q = 2*sqrt(2*db2pow(CarrierPow_Q));

I found that the formula to compute the Amplitude for a sinusoidal signal starting from its power is A = sqrt(2*Power_in_dB) but to obtain the same final power for a BPSK modulated signal I experienced that I have to multiply its amplitude by 2. Why? It's correct?
dataRandN_I = randn(SamplesNum, 1);
dataRandN_Q = randn(SamplesNum, 1);
gNoise = NoiseSigma * dataRandN_I + 1i * NoiseSigma * dataRandN_Q;

Then I start to modulate:
data_bits_I = ... % Array of 1 and 0 values;
data_bits_Q = ... % Array of 1 and 0 values;
RaisedCosine = rcosdesign(0.5, 4, 8, 'sqrt'); %Samples per bit = 8
modData_I = real(pskmod(dataBits_I, 2));
modData_Q = real(pskmod(dataBits_Q, 2));

pulsedShaped_I = upfirdn(modData_I, RaisedCosine, 8); %Samples per bit = 8
pulsedShaped_I = pulsedShaped_I(1:nBits*8);
pulsedShaped_Q = upfirdn(modData_Q, RaisedCosine, 8); %Samples per bit = 8
pulsedShaped_Q = pulsedShaped_Q(1:nBits*8);

signalComp = CarrierAmpl_I * pulsedShaped_I + 1i * CarrierAmpl_Q * pulsedShaped_Q;
signalTx = signalCompFilt .* carrier;  
signalTx_gNoise = signalTx + gNoise;    

The I demodulate the signal and tried to obtain the same starting values.
basebandSignal = signalTx_gNoise .* conj(carrier);
rxFilterOut = upfirdn(basebandSignal, RaisedCosine, 1, 8);

dataOut_I = real(rxFilterOut) < 0;
dataOut_I = imag(rxFilterOut) < 0;

fDelay = 5; % Raised cosine filter span in symbols
[bitError_I, ber_I] = biterr(dataBits_I(1:nBits-fDelay), dataOut_I(fDelay+1:nBits));
[bitError_Q, ber_Q] = biterr(dataBits_Q(1:nBits-fDelay), dataOut_Q(fDelay+1:nBits));

noise_power = pow2db( rms(gNoise)^2 );
signal_power = pow2db( (rms(signalTx_gNoise ) )^2 );
% The signal inlcude noise too, so remove its power
signal_power = pow2db(db2pow(signal_power) - db2pow(noise_power));

SNR = signal_power - noise_power;
CN0 = SNR + 10*log10(BW);

Eb = signal_power - pow2db(Rb);       % dB
N0 = noise_power - pow2db(BW);
EbN0 = Eb - N0;

Or alternatively
EbN0 = SNR + 10*log10(BW/Rb);

Then I repeated these formula separating the components I as real(signal) and Q as imag(signal).
When I execute the code I get this:
Starting from Eb/N0 as 4 I compute all signals and noise power (using power share of 0.1 and 0.9) to be used in modulation:
Eb/N0 = 4.00, CN0 = 74.10 dBHz
Power Ampl = 7.84, Power Ampl I = 2.48, Power Ampl Q = 7.44
Signal Power = 8.85 dB, Signal Power I = -1.15 dB, Signal Power Q = 8.40 dB
Noise Power = 12.54 dB

After demodulation I get:
Error Bit I = 27678/100000, Error Bit Q = 11678/100000
BER_I = 2.767938e-01, BER_Q = 1.167858e-01
CN0 = 74.10 dBHz
SNR = -3.68 dB, SNR_I = -10.79 dB, SNR_Q = -1.11 dB
Signal Power = 8.88 dB, Signal Power I = -1.24 dB, Signal Power Q = 8.43 dB
Noise Power = 12.56 dB, Noise Power I = 9.56 dB, Noise Power Q = 9.55 dB
Eb = -61.22 dB
N0 = -65.22 dB/Hz
Eb/N0 = 3.999 dB, Eb/N0_I = -3.112 dB, Eb/N0_Q = 6.568 dB
Eb/N0 = 3.999 dB, Eb/N0_I = -3.112 dB, Eb/N0_Q = 6.568 dB

with a negative Eb/N0 on I components (I think it's wrong) and a BER/EbN0 values not compliant with theoretical curve.
What I'm missing?
Thank you

Hmm... instead of sips from here and there, fully working source code listing would be better alternative ... .
